# How to place text inside the background image?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on Bootstrap website. I wanted to place text in the right side of the car. I am getting the output as:

[image]

I wanted to place text "hello" in the right side of the Car.

Code:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <figure>
        <img src="images/category/auto.gif" alt=""/>
        <figcaption class="main_service">Hello</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <figure>
        <img src="images/category/auto.gif" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.main_auto      {background:url(images/category/auto.gif) no-repeat;
                  background-size: 35% 75%;


}


.main_service {

width:254px;
    height:136px;
    float:left;
    padding:20px 20px 0 90px;
}
```

I am new to Bootstrap.

Comment: out of the box or within the box

Comment: right side of the car..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao...within the box

Comment: can you create a snippet either or in jsfiddle to show the problem demo?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x2fa9kjv/

Comment: Well, to get this to work, you need to do what @Gaurav has said in his answer since you have to place an element on top of another element and that's why figcaption has to be `position:absolute`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css `position` property. Declare image css position property as relative and text css position property as absolute.
**Code:**

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/category/auto.gif" alt="" class="img-disp" />
            <figcaption class="main_service">Hello</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/category/auto.gif" alt="" class="img-disp" />
            <figcaption class="main_service">Hello</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img-disp{
position: relative;
}

.main_service {
position: absolute;    
....
}
```

Than you can adjust your text position by adding top and left margin to `.main_service` class.

You can see result here : https://jsfiddle.net/8kcsryqy/